# MDX query to get dimension data from another cube

Tags: ssms, mdx, cube

I have two cubes.

I want to inner join the main cube with the other cube and show the data from the dimension where the data exist in another cube.

Comment: I'd do this in the database which is creating the cubes. I don't think MDX is going to be the best solution

Comment: Hi @whytheq Thanks for the reply. Is it possible in MDX to get the least level of data from a hierarchy.
So for example say suppose i have a geography hierarchy and for few geo the least node can be level 5 and for some the least node can be level 6 and so on. 
So how do i get the least level of data?